# Flutter using listview.builder in sliding up panel (The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a sliding up panel whose panel is Column.. and the children is a list view builder with a wrap of container.. but i got this error

```
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.0 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Column
```

this is my sliding up widget

```
Widget _slidingUpWidget(){
    return Container(
      child: SlidingUpPanel(
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
        panel: Column(
          children: [
            userResponseWidget(),
            //caption
            textWidget(),           
            // divider
            dividerWidget(),
            //comment
            commentSectionWidget(dataComment),
            //write comment
            _floatingTextfieldWidget()

          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

and this is the list view builder

```
Widget commentSectionWidget(Comment data){
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: data.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Container(
            child: ItemComment(data.data[index]),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried with wrapping that container with `Expanded()` but it just show half of the content and not scrollable.. i also use `SingleChildScrollView()` but it returns a lot error..

can someone help to fix it?

Comment: it is not scrollable because of NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() it shows half of the content because of SlidingUpPanel minHeight. Also all of your Container(). They aren't doing anything. If you really need to wrap it, use SizedBox(). Remove shrinkwrap true in Listviewbuilder since you've used expanded

Answer (score 1):

Add `SingleChildSrollView` above `Column`, now it should work for you.

**Code:**

```
  Widget _slidingUpWidget(){
    return Container(
        child: SlidingUpPanel(
            minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            panel: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  userResponseWidget(),
                  //caption
                  textWidget(),
                  // divider
                  dividerWidget(),
                  //comment
                  commentSectionWidget(dataComment),
                  //write comment
                  _floatingTextfieldWidget()

                ],
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
```